# Database creation in master

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Now here is the query am trying to run to execute a script that will build up my database according to the script:

```
USE master
GO
if exists (select * from sysdatabases where name='Northwind')
        drop database Northwind
go

DECLARE @device_directory NVARCHAR(520)
SELECT @device_directory = SUBSTRING(filename, 1, CHARINDEX(N'master.mdf', LOWER(filename)) - 1)
FROM master.dbo.sysaltfiles WHERE dbid = 1 AND fileid = 1

EXECUTE (N'CREATE DATABASE Northwind
  ON PRIMARY (NAME = N''Northwind'', FILENAME = N''' + @device_directory + N'northwnd.mdf'')
   LOG ON (NAME = N''Northwind_log'',  FILENAME = N''' + @device_directory + N'northwnd.ldf'')')
go

exec sp_dboption 'Northwind','trunc. log on chkpt.','true'
exec sp_dboption 'Northwind','select into/bulkcopy','true'
GO
```

Now here is the error am getting...

```
Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
Msg 15010, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dboption, Line 64
The database 'Northwind' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases. 

Msg 15010, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dboption, Line 64
The database 'Northwind' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases.
```

Kindly help! The database should be made now in master but its not!

Comment: does your sql user have required privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should have CREATE DATABASE permission to create new datebase. If you are not familiar with this topic, try to login as "sa" user (if you know password), or ask administrator to add your login to "sysadmin" role at SQL Server.